# two field sets in a django-tastypie ModelResource class

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to find a way to create two sets of fields in a django-tastypie ModelResource class. I'd like one set to return all fields of the model while the other to return only a subset of the fields. I could create two ModelResource classes with each one having two fields sets, however, i am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dehydrating the content type by adding this method to my resource

```
def dehydrate(self,bundle):
    bundle.data['type'] = bundle.obj.content_type
    return bundle
```

then I filtered the data on the client side. Its not an ideal solution, but good enough for now